# Autoformating of inline code in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Are there any way to turn of the autoformatting of C# code that is inlined inside HTML when making a MVC application?

It seems that it use the C# Text Editor settings for the inline code as well, but I don't want to use the same formatting inside the HTML file as the normal code files.

For example, if I write `<% somecodehere { %>`, then some HTML in between, and then I put the `<% } %>` at the end, Visual Studio automatically reformats the code to this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
  ...
<%
 }%>
```

For the MVC code, I think it looks much tidyer like this

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()){ %>
  ...
<% } %>
```

But I don't see how to change this without messing up the formatting for my normal code files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've myself tried to do this but to no prevail. If you get it to work so that it looks good in one place, it will look bad in another. My best recommendation is to switch to razor, there are ways to use webform views and razor views in the same project to provide seamless migration.

http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2011/01/07/Using-Razor-Pages-with-WebForms-Master-Pages.aspx

Comment: It seems that this is the only viable option available. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn this off by going to:
Tools|Options on the left (you may need to check "show all settings") expand Text Editor. In the language you need, probably in your case the HTML bit, in formatting, you can uncheck "automatically format on..." there are a few options, that should do it.

Comment: That's the problem actually. You can't set that option for HTML, since HTML has no editor setting for what happens when you set the closing } (since HTML do not have any closing }'s)

Comment: Yes, but as mentioned, I *want* this in the code files. So I want different behaviors for the code files, and the HTML files, but it does not seem to be possible.

Comment: I see, I'm not sure if you can have 2 behaviours for the same code type. I'll keep an eye out for you though.